# Pjsip Android Video Call: How to display your view in a SurfaceView using Pjsip Library

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I am implementing **SIP Video Call** using Pjsip library.

My view is successfully transmitted to other person but what I want is to display my camera view in my screen(Something like **WhatsApp**).

I found that **Pjsip is using camera** to transmit view. How can I display my Camera View in a **SurfaceView** using Pjsip library(as **I can not use multiple instances of Camera**)?

I have already tried this using the following code:

```
fun updateVideoPreview(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
if (SipManager.getInstance()?.activeCalls?.get(callId) != null &&
        SipManager.getInstance()?.activeCalls?.get(callId)?.mVideoWindow != null &&
        SipManager.getInstance()?.activeCalls?.get(callId)?.mVideoPreview != null) {
    if (videoPreviewActive) {
        val vidWH = VideoWindowHandle()
        vidWH.handle?.setWindow(holder.surface)
        val vidPrevParam = VideoPreviewOpParam()
        vidPrevParam.window = vidWH
        vidPrevParam.show = true
        try {
            SipManager.getInstance()?.activeCalls?.get(callId)?.mVideoPreview?.start(vidPrevParam)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }
    } else {
        try {
            SipManager.getInstance()?.activeCalls?.get(callId)?.mVideoPreview?.stop()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I executed this code what I found is the preview that is transmitted to other side(**mirror effect**) but what I want is my own view.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:
- Replaced SurfaceView with TextureView and

```
if (isFrontCamera) {
    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f)
    matrix.postTranslate(width.toFloat(), 0.0f)
    surfacePreviewCapture.setTransform(matrix)
}
```

It worked for me. Hope it help others.

Comment: Yes. But not accurate @SonPham

Comment: I have problem when start and stop start transmit media, sometimes my app freeze when changed state.

Comment: How can i contact with you? (Skype or Messager)

Comment: Can you share some pjmedia_video_format_detail @Aanal Mehta. This is my config
            cp.enc_fmt.det.vid.size.w = 720;
            cp.enc_fmt.det.vid.size.h = 1280; 
            cp.enc_fmt.det.vid.avg_bps = 500*1000;
            cp.enc_fmt.det.vid.max_bps = 1024*2*1000;
            cp.enc_fmt.det.vid.fps.num = 30;
            cp.enc_fmt.det.vid.fps.denum = 1;

Comment: Aanal Mehta can you help me

Comment: @SonPham Here is my Video Codec format /*Set Video Codecs*/
        val param = ep?.getVideoCodecParam("H264")
        val encFormatVideo = param?.encFmt
        val decFormatVideo = param?.decFmt
        encFormatVideo?.height = 320
        encFormatVideo?.width = 240
        decFormatVideo?.height = 320
        decFormatVideo?.width = 240
        param?.encFmt = encFormatVideo
        param?.decFmt = decFormatVideo
        ep?.setVideoCodecParam("H264", param)